# how to upload a parquet file into Azure ADLS 2 Blob

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-explorer

Hi i want to upload Parquet files to ADLS gen 2 blob. I am using below line of code to create blob and upload parquet file in it.

```
blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="Connection String", container_name="parquet", blob_name=outdir)
df.to_parquet('logs.parquet',compression='GZIP') #df is dataframe
with open("./logs.parquet", "rb") as data:
blob.upload_blob(data)
os.remove("logs.parquet")
```

**i do not face any error and the files are also written in the blob. But , i don't think i am doing it right as ADX/kusto query can not understand the file and no data is visible there.**

Below are the steps i performed in Azure Data Explorer to fetch records from uploaded parquet file in ADLS gen 2.

**Created External Table:**

```
.create external table LogDataParquet(AppId_s:string,UserId_g:string,Email_s:string,RoleName_s:string,Operation_s:string,EntityId_s:string,EntityType_s:string,EntityName_s:string,TargetTitle_s:string,TimeGenerated:datetime) 
kind=blob
dataformat=parquet
( 
   h@'https://streamoutalds2.blob.core.windows.net/stream-api-raw-testing;secret'
)
with 
(
   folder = "ExternalTables"   
)
```

**External Table Column Mapping :**

```
.create external table LogDataParquet parquet mapping "LogDataMapparquet" '[{ "column" : "AppId_s", "path" : "$.AppId_s"},{ "column" : "UserId_g", "path" : "$"},{ "column" : "Email_s", "path" : "$.Email_s"},{ "column" : "RoleName_s", "path" : "$.RoleName_s"},{ "column" : "Operation_s", "path" : "$.Operation_s"},{ "column" : "EntityId_s", "path" : "$.EntityId_s"}]'
```

**External Tables Gives no records**

```
external_table('LogDataParquet')
```

No records

```
external_table('LogDataParquet') | count
```

1 record - count 0

*I have used similar scenario using stream analytics , where i receive incoming streams and save it in parquet format to ADLS. External table in ADX fetches records well in that case. I feel i am making mistake in the way parquet files are written in blob - (with open("./logs.parquet", "rb") as data: )*

Comment: Can you please provide more details on the error you see with the Kusto query?

Comment: i do not see any error with kusto , but it does not fetches any records . Just empty rows.

Comment: If you see empty rows (and count of empty rows matches the count of input rows in the parquet file) - this may suggest that your ingestion mapping is incorrect.
The question does not specify how the data lands in ADX after uploaded into a blob. Are you using EventGrid or using ADX python library for ingesting the data?
Please, clarify.

Comment: Empty rows and the counts are 0 as well. i am using ADX python library for ingesting data   (from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient, BlobClient)
. i have edited the question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

According to logs, external table was defined as follows:

```
.create external table LogDataParquet(AppId_s:string,UserId_g:string,Email_s:string,RoleName_s:string,Operation_s:string,EntityId_s:string,EntityType_s:string,EntityName_s:string,TargetTitle_s:string,TimeGenerated:datetime) 
kind=blob
partition by 
   AppId_s,
   bin(TimeGenerated,1d)
dataformat=parquet
( 
   '******'
)
with 
(
   folder = "ExternalTables"   
)
```

The `PARTITION BY` clause tells ADX that the expected folder layout is:

```
<AppId_s>/<TimeGenerated, formatted as 'yyyy/MM/dd'>
```

For example:

```
https://streamoutalds2.blob.core.windows.net/stream-api-raw-testing;secret/SuperApp/2020/01/31
```

You can find more info on how ADX locates files on external storage during a query, in this section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/external-tables-azurestorage-azuredatalake#artifact-filtering-logic

To fix the external table definition in accordance to folders layout, please use `.alter` command:

```
.alter external table LogDataParquet(AppId_s:string,UserId_g:string,Email_s:string,RoleName_s:string,Operation_s:string,EntityId_s:string,EntityType_s:string,EntityName_s:string,TargetTitle_s:string,TimeGenerated:datetime) 
kind=blob
dataformat=parquet
( 
  h@'https://streamoutalds2.blob.core.windows.net/stream-api-raw-testing;secret'
)
with 
(
   folder = "ExternalTables"   
)
```

BTW, if a mapping is naive (e.g. mapped column names match data source column names), then it's not needed for Parquet format.

Comment: yes the table definition is expecting data partition with 'App_id and Date' and same is maintained in ADLS blob as well  . I did not mentioned about partitions since i have worked with it in different scenarios and don't think the issue is there .  Also , even if i remove all partition definition from external table and give complete path of a parquet file from ADLS blob , still table does not fetches any record. i do not face any issue with set of parquet file written by Azure Stream Analytics but only with Python SDK .

Comment: Can you upload sample Parquet file somewhere?

Comment: @ashwiniprakash I don't have access to the data. It would really help if you just upload sample Parquet file on some public service. Thanks!

Comment: Please find parquet file in my git repository 'https://github.com/ashwini-git/datastore.git' . Thank You !

Comment: I used pyarrow instead of fastparquet and its working.